# Segmentation fault when trying to free memory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have below code where I have commented when I get segmentation fault and when not.

Originally I got segmentation fault and then I could figure out that probably I cannot initialize my char pointer locations like `"abcd"`. But I am not able to understand - WHY?

I thought `testString = "abcd";` will put `a` at first memory address, `b` at second and so on ...

Segmentation fault occurs when trying to free memory, based on how I initialize memory location.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* testString = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);

    printf("Size of char is: %d\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("Size of int is: %d\n", sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Pointer addresses are: %p\n", testString + i);
    }

    char* tempPtr = testString + 2;
    printf("My temp pointer address = %p\n", tempPtr);

    // This gives me segmentation fault ....
    testString = "abcd";

    // This will not give me segmentation fault ....    
    //int count = 65;
    //for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    //{
    //    testString[i] = count + i;
    //}

    printf("Printing character...\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Characters are: %c\n", testString[i]);
    }

    printf("Freeing memory...\n");
    free(testString);

    //printf("Access after freeing >>%c<<\n", tempPtr[0]);
    //free(testString);
}
```

---

Based on @M.M. and @Jonathan's comment I understood that with `testString = "abcd";` my `testString` will point to a memory location where string "abcd" was created and since I didn't malloc'ed it I cannot free it. Also, since my original pointer to heap memory (which I got using malloc) is gone, so it is waste of memory or memory lead.

So, does it means that when I use printf statement like `printf("Printing character...\n");`, this is also a memory leak? Then how do I avoid it? Looping and inserting into char* is certainly a bad idea.

Comment: `testString = "abcd"` means that the pointer `testString` will now point to the memory location containing `"abcd"`. Then you try to `free` that location, causing segmentation fault.

Comment: Note that `testString = "abcd";` throws away the pointer to the allocated memory (a memory leak).  You need `strcpy()` instead, perhaps.  And since the string literal (pointer value) was not returned by `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or `realloc()`), you can't free it.

Comment: @l3x I didn't want to use some build-in functions and wanted to achieve most basic ways. Thanks for comment though.

Comment: The memory leak occurs because `testString` contains the only pointer to the allocated memory.  When you assign `testString = "abcd"`, you assign a new, different pointer value to `testString`.  You can no longer free the pointer that was returned by `malloc()` because you no longer have a record of what it was.  The string `"abcd"` exists in your program's memory space somewhere; it isn't a memory leak.  It's the pointer overwrite that causes the leak.  The `printf("…")` operation does not leak memory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No problem buddy, thanks for your fresh comment. I got it now. So, if I am correct then string "abcd" will be created in stack segment of memory? I don't think it would be created in data segment, and I am not sure about heap segment.

Comment: The string `"abcd"` will exist somewhere in memory.  It is quite likely to be in the text segment since string literals are read-only, but the standard doesn't mandate anything about segments.  It won't be in the heap area managed by `malloc()`; it probably won't be on the stack, either.  It will most likely either be in the data segment or in the text segment — these days, in the text segment, though historically, it would have been in the data segment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As per my `C` installation, it got created in text segment. I verified using `size` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Comment: these two lines result in the compiler outputting two warning messages. `printf("Size of char is: %d\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("Size of int is: %d\n", sizeof(int));`  because the format specifier is expecting an integer parameter and the the returned type from `sizeof()` is `size_t`  Suggest changing to: `printf("Size of char is: %lu\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("Size of int is: %lu\n", sizeof(int));`

Comment: 1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.   multiplying by 1 has absolutely no effect on the parameter passed to `malloc()` and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the expression: `sizeof(char)`.    2) when calling any of the memory allocation function, like `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding this expression. `printf("Pointer addresses are: %p\n", testString + i);`.  there is only one pointer: `testString` and the addresses of the bytes within the allocated memory are going to be consecutive,  so are of little to no worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c) has content relevant to answer of my question but doesn't have detailed answer. @Jonathan's comments answers all my questions but he hasn't put forward a detailed answer so I am writing my answer so that folks who will visit further can have detailed explanation:

I created a pointer and allocated some space on **"heap segment" of the memory**, now my pointer was pointing to that memory location on heap.
Code relevant for all this is - `char* testString = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);`.

Now, when I dis this - `testString = "abcd";` then string "abcd" is created in **"text/code segment"** (or in some implementation data segment) of the memory and memory address is returned and assigned to my pointer `testString`.
What happens is that my original pointer which was pointing a memory location on heap is lost and the pointer started pointing to a memory location on text/code segment of the memory.

**Implication of all this:**

- It has resulted in **memory leak** because my original pointer which was pointing to the heap memory is lost, so now I have **no way to free that heap memory** and hence memory leak.
- When I will try to free that memory using `free(testString);` then I will get segmentation fault (***this is exactly what has happened to me***) because **`free()`** can only be used to free the memory which is allocated using either malloc, calloc or realloc. Now, since the pointer `testString` is pointing to a memory location on text/code segment and I had not allocated that memory using some C memory allocation method, so I cannot free it using `free()` and if I do so then I get segmentation fault.
- When I do `testString = "abcd"` (when testString is a pointer) then I cannot access the memory location pointed by `testString` because the memory allocated is read-only in text/code segment of the memory. So, `testString[0] = 'x'` will also result in segmentation fault.

**What happens when I do `printf("hello, world")`?:**
This will create "hello, world" string as read-only in text/code segment of memory. I verified that it does create in text/code segment in C99 implementation using `size` command.

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
testString = "abcd";
```

is overlaying the pointer given by the call to `malloc()` with the address of the string literal: `"abcd"`   this results in a memory leak because the original pointer to the allocated memory is lost.

In C, when copying a string, it 'should' be handled by the functions: `strcpy()` and `strncpy()` which will not corrupt the pointer contained in `testString`.

```
strcpy( testString, "abcd" );
strncpy( testString, "abcd", strlen( "abcd" ) );
```

Naturally, once the pointer to the allocated memory has been overlayed/destroyed by the assignment statement: `testString = "abcd";`, the new value placed into `testString` must not be passed to `free()`

the seg fault would be happening at the call to `free()`, not at the incorrect assignment of a new pointer to `testString`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesn't comprehensively answers my questions.

Comment: @hagrawal,  there is only one line in your posted code that causes a memory leak: `testString = "abcd";`   a call to `printf()` should never cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Using `printf` is *not* a memory leak. Memory leaks occur when a pointer is allocated via `malloc` [or, herein, `strdup`] and there is no corresponding `free` call for it.

Also, trying to free a pointer that has *not* been allocated is another type of error. It [probably] won't segfault, but `free` will complain.

Here's a simplified version of your program that illustrates some of the ways you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int opt_segv;

char *temp = "abcd";

void
dostr(char *str,int modflg)
{

    printf("\n");
    printf("dostr: %s\n",str);
    if (modflg)
        str[modflg] = 'm';
    printf("dostr: %s\n",str);
}

void
test1(void)
{
    int len;
    char *testString;

    len = strlen(temp);
    testString = malloc(len + 1);
    strcpy(testString,temp);

    dostr(testString,1);

    free(testString);
}

void
test2(void)
{
    char *testString;

    testString = strdup(temp);

    dostr(testString,2);

    free(testString);
}

void
test3(void)
{
    char *testString;

    // passing a pointer to a string _constant_ -- do _not_ modify
    testString = temp;

    dostr(testString,opt_segv ? 3 : 0);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 's':  // generate segfault
            opt_segv = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    test1();
    test2();
    test3();

    return 0;
}
```

You can run the program with `-s` to simulate the string constant modification that caused your segfault.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesn't comprehensively answers my questions.  If you had described using comments or some write-up on what you wanted to show from the code example then it would have been better.